# Can I insert a scrollview before a view in IOS?

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

The answer can be for swift, objective-c or c# even if I'm using xamarin.
I have issues creating scrollview in the storyboard with xamarin, I followed several tutorial for xcode but I can't do what I need.

Then I removed the scrollview and just have a long vertical uiview and actualy added some code to scroll it using pangesture moving the uiview frame.

But I know it would be better to use srollview also I though that it must be possible to insert a scrollview before the view (in code) to achieve the same thing.

So is it possible ?

Comment: Why yes it is possible and if you show some of the code you have or have tried then we might be able to show you how to do it in your project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible, for example you could do this in your ViewController by adding the ScrollView as a subview to your View.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let scrollViewFrame = view.bounds
    let scrollView = UIScrollView(frame: scrollViewFrame)
    scrollView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
    scrollView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    view.addSubview(scrollView)

    let innerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50))
    innerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    scrollView.addSubview(innerView)

    scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: scrollViewFrame.width, height: scrollViewFrame.height * 2)
}
```

In this example the ScrollView has the same size as the main View. You can adjust this by changing the `scrollViewFrame` constant.

The `innerView` has a fixed size of 50x50. If it should cover the entire scrollView, just use the `scrollViewFrame` and the same `autoresizingMask`.

I adjusted the `contentSize` to be twice as high as the `scrollView` in order to make it scroll. This might or might not be necessary for your solution.

Comment: and don't forget anytime the frame of the view changes you will need to update the frame of the scroll view (or use auto-layout).

Comment: @UpholderOfTruth Good point, I updated my answer and set the autoresizingMask accordingly.

Comment: Sorry if I misunderstand butit just adds a scrollview to my actual view, I need the view to be added to a scroll view. I though about unlinking the view from the superview, adding a scroll view and link the view to the scrollview as a child...

Comment: @Entretoize I expanded my answer and added an innerView to the scrollView.

Comment: OK, but my view content (created in storyboard) is still in the View not in the the innerview, sorry if I was unclear.

Comment: I just tried that: `View.RemoveFromSuperview();

            var scrollViewFrame = View.Bounds;
            var scrollView = new UIScrollView(scrollViewFrame);
            scrollView.AutoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight;
            scrollView.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Red;
            scrollView.AddSubview(View);
            View=scrollView;` It shows the scrollview with the view on it but I can't scroll. Maybe because of some constraints...

Comment: @Entretoize Have you set the contentSize as described above?

Comment: This is it ! Adding contentSize worked, so is my code correct ?

Comment: @Entretoize I would not recommend to rearrange the views in another way then storyboard sets them up. I might work, but might as well lead to side-effects, so you never can be sure. I would create the innerView programmatically and not fiddle around with storyboard at all. Another solution might be to create a specific storyboard for the innerView and load the innerView from that storyboard programmatically in your viewDidLoad().